# Flask-SQLAlchemy db query on dropdown menu ajax

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am attempting to use ajax to get a query from a database by using the change function on a dropdown so the page doesn't need to reload. I keep getting the error "ValueError: View function did not return a response" I changed code I used on a search feature for django using ajax just like this but now I don't see where I went wrong. This is what my code looks like. The dropdown menu is a Flask-WTForm select field. No longer am I getting the traceback error but I still do not have any data returned.

ajax.js

```
var csrftoken = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content')

$.ajaxSetup({
beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
    if (!/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/i.test(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken)
    }
  }
})

$(function() {
$('#client').change(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/eventselect",
        data: {
            'eventview': $('#client').val(),
        },
        success: eventSuccess,
        dataType: 'html'
    });
  });
});

function eventSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
{
    $('#eventslog').html(data);
}
```

views.py

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
# @login_required
def home():
    viewform = EventViewForm()
    return render_template('home.html', viewform=viewform)


@app.route('/eventselect', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def eventselect():
    viewform = EventViewForm()
    today = datetime.today()
    posted1 = '%i-%i-%i 00:00:00' % (today.year, today.month, today.day)
    posted2 = '%i-%i-%i 23:59:59' % (today.year, today.month, today.day)
    if viewform.validate_on_submit():
        eventview = viewform.data
        print(eventview)
        if eventview is not None and eventview !=u"":
            eventview = viewform.data
            if eventview == 'client1':
                eventview = EventsClient1
            elif eventview == 'client2':
                eventview = EventsClient2
            else:
                eventview = EventsClient3
            eventviewlogs = eventview.query.filter(eventview.posted.between(posted1, posted2))
    else:
        eventviewlogs = []
    return render_template('eventselect.html', eventviewlogs=eventviewlogs)
```

eventselect.html

```
{% if eventviewlogs.count() > 0 %}
  {% for ev in eventviewlogs %}
    {{ ev.posted }} | {{ ev.poster }} | {{ ev.event }}
  {% endfor %}
{% elif eventviewlogs.count() = 0 %}
  No items found
{% endif %}
```

home.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
  {% block content %}
  {{ viewform.client() }}
  <div id="eventslog"></div>
{% endblock content %}
```

traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1478, in full_dispatch_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1566, in make_response
    raise ValueError('View function did not return a response')
ValueError: View function did not return a response
```

Comment: What is `{{ viewform.client() }}` and what does it do?

Comment: @Leandro Poblet that is the selectfield that has the list of clients

Comment: I am not going directly to /eventselect but to have it displayed on /

Comment: fixed the if count statement in post needed () but still same traceback error

Comment: add the home view to the post I have it now where I don't get a traceback error but it still is not pulling any data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it working by fixing my call to eventselect. I was not getting the request.data

```
@app.route('/eventselect/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def eventselect():
    today = datetime.today()
    posted1 = '%i-%i-%i 00:00:00' % (today.year, today.month, today.day)
    posted2 = '%i-%i-%i 23:59:59' % (today.year, today.month, today.day)
    if request.method == "POST":
        eventview = request.data
        print(eventview)
        # if eventview is not None and eventview !=u"":
        #     eventview = viewform.data
        if eventview == 'EventsClient1':
            eventview = EventsClient1
        elif eventview == 'EventsClient2':
            eventview = EventsClient2
        else:
            eventview = EventsClient3
        print(eventview)
        eventviewlogs = eventview.query.filter(eventview.posted.between(posted1, posted2))
    else:
        eventviewlogs = []
    return render_template('eventselect.html', eventviewlogs=eventviewlogs)
```